# filereader result order changing while uploading multiple images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, filereader

I am trying to upload multiple images and place in separate img tag using Javascript. Here is what I tried,

MyJsp.jsp :

```
  <div>
  <img alt="Image1" id="Image1" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image2" id="Image2" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image3" id="Image3" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br> 
  <img alt="Image4" id="Image4" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  <img alt="Image5" id="Image5" src="" width="130px" height="90px"><br><br>
  </div>

<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg"/ multiple>
<input type="text" id="imginsert" value="1">
```

MyJS.js :

```
$(function(){
document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
        
function handleFileSelect(evt) {    
    
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
   // alert("1");
   // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
   for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      
     // Only process image files.
     if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
       continue;
     }

     var reader = new FileReader();   
     reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
       return function(e) {
           var count=$('#imginsert').val();
                if(count==1){
                    
                $('#Image1').attr("src",e.target.result);
                $('#imginsert').val('2');
                
                //alert("first :"+e.target.result);
                }
                else if(count==2)
                {
                    
                    //alert("else if 1");
                    $('#Image2').attr("src",e.target.result);
                    $('#imginsert').val('3');
                    
                    //alert("2 :"+e.target.result);
                }
                else if(count==3)
                {
                    
                    //alert("else if 2");
                    $('#Image3').prop("src",e.target.result);
                    $('#imginsert').val('4');
                    
                    //alert("3 :"+e.target.result);
                }
                else if(count==4)
                {
                    
                    $('#Image4').prop("src",e.target.result);
                    $('#imginsert').val('5');
                    
                    //alert("4 :"+e.target.result);
                }
                else if(count==5)
                {
                    
                    $('#Image5').prop("src",e.target.result);
                    $('#imginsert').val('6');
                    
                    //alert("5 :"+e.target.result);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("You can upload only 5 images.");
                }
                            
       };
       
     })(f); 

     // Read in the image file as a data URL.
     reader.readAsDataURL(f);
   }

 }
        
});
```

If I'm uploading Img1.jpg,Img2.jpg,Img3.jpg,Img4.jpg,Img5.jpg means the OP is:

```
Img2.jpg
Img4.jpg
Img1.jpg
Img3.jpg
Img5.jpg
```

My expected OP is :

```
Img1.jpg
Img2.jpg
Img3.jpg
Img4.jpg
Img5.jpg
```

where am I doing a mistake is it to place orderly like uploading images order?

Comment: why is the order in you backend necessary?

Comment: @Nano sorry i couldnt get you!?

Comment: If you **upload** multiple images to your backend, you usaly dont mix pictures if you want to do different things with them (if thats the reason why the order is important).

Comment: @Nano yes i m trying this like match the following question(Image To Text) so i want to place and show orderly from uploading images,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readAsDataURL` is asynchronous so you can't guarantee that they will finish in any order. Just pass the index of the file to your IIFE with your file

```
 reader.onload = (function(theFile, count) {
   return function(e) {
            if (count > 5)
            {
                alert("You can upload only 5 images.");
            }
            else{
                $('#Image'+count).prop("src",e.target.result);
            }

   };

 })(f,i+1);
```

Comment: Thank You for valuable answer.Its working fine like what i expected.